# How to add validation for telephone number in magento customer registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, validation

I'm very new in magento and will appreciate if someone can give me a step-by -step procedure to 2 validations in the customer registration form in Magento 1.9.

1. The size of telephone number field should be 10 and numeric
2. Zipcode should not accept alphabets.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add validate class for validation in magento 1.

For **Phone Number** Validation

```
'validate-phoneStrict'          => 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.'
'validate-phoneLax'             => 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.'
'validate-fax'                  => 'Please enter a valid fax number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.'
```

For **Zip Code** Validation

```
'validate-zip'                  => 'Please enter a valid zip code. For example 90602 or 90602-1234.'
'validate-zip-international'    => 'Please enter a valid zip code.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this Link:-

http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

OR

you can use these classes to validate the Telephone number:-

```
'validate-phoneStrict'          => 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.'
'validate-phoneLax'             => 'Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.'
```

**EX:-** `<input class="required validate-phoneStrict" id="field1" name="field1" />`

Comment: Can someone please give a step-by-step way to implement this. Please treat me as a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: Just  go to the phtml of the Registration page app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

find the field to which your field is generated and the above said class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension, it automatically adds validation based on the selected country with the country flags and automatically sets the user country by default based on their Geo IP location.

https://marketplace.magento.com/ananta-module-telephonevalidation.html